# Rails, saving the foreign key in a `belongs_to` association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think I'm having a really basic problem here but I can't seem to put my finger on what I'm doing wrong.

So the issue here is when I save an instance of a model the `foreign_key` for the models's `belongs_to` association (in this case the `user_id` is not being saved, so I'm forced to do this:

```
def new
  @thing = Thing.new(:user_id => current_user.id)
end

def create
  @thing = Thing.new(params[:thing])
  @thing.user_id = current_user.id

  if @thing.save
    redirect_to @thing
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Shouldn't the `user_id` get saved automatically if my model has this association?

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The reason I'm having this issue in the first place is because the gem `friendly_id` has changed the way all of my `ids` work and now return the objects slug... pretty annoying in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try `@thing.user = User.find(current_user.id)` instead in your controller. Have you also got the `has_many :things` association declared in your user model?